# applying middleware on store is not called reducer correctly in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i'm making website with React + Redux. before i added middleware, application works fine, but after added, reducer not dispatching correctly.

this is my code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

...

let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore);

let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(appReducer);

store.dispatch(updateText('text changed.'));
```

and this is my action creator just used above:

```
const UPDATE_TEXT = 'UPDATE_TEXT';

function updateText(text = '') {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_TEXT,
        text
    };
}
```

and this is appReducer:

```
const defaultState = { text: 'default' };
function appReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case UPDATE_TEXT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                text: action.text
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

if i just remove applyMiddleware and create store directly with use createStore like this:

```
let store = createStore(appReducer);
```

it works fine! but i really want to use middlewares. what should i do? anyone gimme a hand will be very appreciate!

Comment: Have you tried `createStore(appReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(logger))`?

Comment: Is the `logger` middleware you're using redux-logger? If so, are you importing it as `createLogger` and then setting `const logger = createLogger()`?

Comment: oh, thanks Shane! you are correct. i think i read old tutorial so i think usage is different. thanks.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere Write your comment as answer so that I can accept it XD

Comment: @modernator Done, and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger) (which you may be using), the initial import was a function that needed to first be called like this:

```
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
const logger = createLogger()
```

Then you could use `logger` as middleware:

```
...
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore)
...
```

However, in the current version, you can simply `import logger from 'redux-logger'` and use it that way. If you want to create a logger with custom options, you can `import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'`.